# Same Occurrence of two numbers in sub arrays (contiguous)

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

**Given an array of integers ,find total number of contiguous sub-sequence that has same number of x and y.**
*For example array [1,2,1] for x=1 and y=2
   ans = 2 for its two sub arrays [1,2] and [2,1].*
**Checking every contiguous sub-sequence is O(n^2) which is too inefficient. Any idea for improvements?**

this is the code i have written

```
int get_total(int* a,int x,int y,int n){
    int result=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int x_c=0,y_c=0;
        for(int j=i;j<n;j++){
            if(a[j]==x){
                x_c++;
            }
            if(a[j]==y){
                y_c++;
            }
            if(x_c==y_c){
                result++;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(){
    int n,q;
    cin >>n >>q;
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin >>a[i];
    }
    while(q--){
        int x,y;
        cin >>x >>y;
        cout <<get_total(a,x,y,n)<<"\n";
    }
}
```

it runs in n^2 for every query.
max array size is 8*10^3 and max number of query is 10^5

Comment: Please show something about how you've researched this and what you found out about it so far.

Comment: This sounds like the string searching problem. You can use (with modifications) Knuth-Morris-Pratt or a finite automata.

Comment: I don't understood how to to apply Knuth-Morris-Pratt or finite automata for this problem @ macmoonshine

Comment: Review of functional code is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Such questions belong on [codereview.se].

Comment: @Makyen This is not code review question. This is a question, where the asker shows his attempt to solve it (and described why it's not good), as expected in how to ask a question.

Comment: @amit, that's for when they haven't gotten it to function. At best, I consider it debatable. "Any idea for improvements?" isn't an SO question. We appear to disagree, so should search meta/ask there. Code Review is *explicitly* for review of **working** code wrt.: ["Best practices and design pattern usage", B) "Security issues", C) "**Performance**", and D) "Correctness in unanticipated cases".](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This question is asking about how to improve the performance of already working code, which is specifically on-topic for [codereview.se].

Comment: What a coincidence!!!!! https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w34/challenges/same-occurrence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an auxillary array `x_y_diffs`, which is essentially:

```
#(times_x_appeared_thus_far) - #(times_y_appeared_thus_far)
```

And can be calculated as:

```
x_y_diffs[0] = 0
x_y_diffs[i] = x_y_diffs[i-1] + 1         if array[i-1] == x
               x_y_diffs[i-1] - 1         if array[i-1] == y
               x_y_diffs[i-1]             otherwise
```

It is easy to see it can be calculated in linear time.

Now, observe that a "good" subsequence (i,j) begins and ends where `x_y_diffs[i+1] == x_y_diffs[j+1]`.

So, you can simply iterate the array and maintain a histogram counting how many times each value occurd.

```
std::map<int, int> histogram;
int count = 0;
for (int x : x_y_diffs) {
  count += histogram[x];
  histogram[x] = histogram[x] + 1;
}
```

This takes `O(nlogn)` time to calculate (each map insert/seek is `O(logn)`), and can be improved to `O(n)` *average case* by switching from `std::map` to `std::unordred_map`.

So, the algorithm is total `O(n)` or `O(nlogn)` time (based on map selection) - and `O(n)` additional space.

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/snC9KU)